# read data from one txt file and write selected data into another txt file in android/java

Tags: java, android, file, file-io

I have one txt file in my android project. I want to read this file and parse data of this file and write selected data to another .txt file. My orignal file datais like (I have more than 2000 data like)

```
Pramod (Deore)|^*|^PPD|^|$Yogesh (Gadage)|^YMG|^Nasik|^|$Vishal (Chaudhary)|^*|^VRC|^|$Sagar (Pawar)|^*|^SGP|^|$Pramod (Deore)|^*|^PPD|^|$Yogesh (Gadage)|^YMG|^Nasik|^|$Vishal (Chaudhary)|^*|^VRC|^|$Sagar (Pawar)|^*|^SGP|^|$
```

Now I want to read this data and in second file as:

```
Pramod (Deore)|$Yogesh (Gadage)|$Vishal (Chaudhary)|$Sagar (Pawar)|$Pramod (Deore)|$Yogesh (Gadage)|$Vishal (Chaudhary)|$Sagar (Pawar)|$
```

any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can read Everything in a file to String

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append('\n');
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        String everything = sb.toString();
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
```

And here is how you can write to file. So read from first file and write to other.

```
try {
          File file = new File("example.txt");
          BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
          output.write(text);
          output.close();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now all you have to do is come-up with logic to achieve what you want to do. Also please not that storing everything into a the String `everything` is not a good idea because it will consume a lot of VM space.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below to parse the input data to get output that you want :

```
String line = br.readLine(); //Read Your input line
String[] ans = line.split("\\|");
String a="";
for(int i=0;i<ans.length;i+=4){
    a=a+" "+ans[i];
}
System.out.println(a); //it will print your desired output
```